# What happens when an object tries to access deallocated unowned object?

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

if **A** is declared as `unowned var` and is then deallocated, What happens when another object tries to access **A**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unowned references, like weak references, do not increase the retain count of the object being referred. However, in Swift, an unowned reference has the added benefit of not being an Optional. This makes them easier to manage rather than resorting to using optional binding. This is not unlike Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals. In addition, unowned references are non-zeroing. This means that when the object is deallocated, it does not zero out the pointer. This means that use of unowned references can, in some cases, lead to dangling pointers. In the Objective-C world, unowned references map to `unsafe_unretained` references.

So, it will raise a `Fatal Error` like:

> Fatal error: Attempted to read an unowned reference but object X was already deallocated

<sub>As a `signal SIGABRT`</sub>